# Vue js DOM not updating

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a few components: A, B , C
in component A i have an array.

When i select an item from component A:

I have an `emit` to a method in component B that show filesArray.length with `data:{filesArray:[]}`

Inside component B i have component C with `props: filesArray`

When i'm adding a file
in component C it looks like this: `filesArray.push(myFile);`

My issue:
When i select an item from component A and then adding a file in component C

- for the first few times it's updating the filesArray.length and i can see the length of the array.
- for the third or firth time it show filesArray.length 0 even if push item in component C.

What have i tried: return filesArray.length in component B as computed:

```
 computed:{
    filesArrayLength(){
      debugger
      return this.filesArray.length;
    }
  },
```

and it didn't work, and i have tried to use watch.
and it also didn't work

Comment: Can you show us your 3 components ? Not sure you can update a prop directly.

Comment: I have too much code. In Component A:
I'm doing emit to a method in Component B that has an filesArray.
And in HTML i'm showing the length.
Component C has props:  filesArray and a method that doing: this.$props.filesArray.push(myFile);

Comment: Then read up on how to create a minimal, concrete and verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Without any code we can’t tell you what could’ve possibly gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't mutate props directly, and even if you do I don't think you can expect it to reliably update the data in the parent. Component C should be emitting an event whenever you want to add an item to `filesArray` so that Component B can append it.